# Need help on SQL Server data compression, hope to compress more on a large table

Tags: sql-server, compression, magento

We have made good progress following our [previous question about SQL Server data compression](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/332061/how-to-compress-data-in-sql-server-the-data-warehouse-raw-data-is-times-bigger). For one of the tables, we compressed it from 20 GB to 2 GB, so this proves that the best compression ratio can get up to 10 times.

Another table's size, measured as the table's reserved space, reduced from 72.55 GB to 67.06 GB. So, its compression benefit is not enough if compared with the best case above.

The same as the previous question, we are working on a data warehouse for a Magento-v2 application, and the table name is `msab_magento.sales_order_item`.

- This table also contains a large number of `null` values in various columns.
- However, this table contains a `product_option` column in type `nvarchar(max)` corresponding to the same column in the MySQL source in type `text`. And this column stores JSON format text data. Per row, the average string length on this column is `4923`, or `9 KB` as each character takes two bypes in `nvarchar`.

Regarding the JSON column, our tentative thoughts are:

- Since SQL Server page-level compression works on the individual pages of size `8 KB` each. So, the page size is smaller than the column's size. So, this may affect the compression.
- The JSON documents come from the templates in product configuration, filled with specific information per transaction. If the consecutive transactions are not for the same product, their JSON fields will be generated from different templates, and have different keys. This makes it difficult to apply the Dictionary compression algorithm.
- Nevertheless, in the global data set, each product will have large number orders, so the JSON keys are still repeating a lot, just maybe across longer range than one page (`8 KB`)'s size.

**Our Question:**

- We want to make the data compression even better and need directions. Please also remind us if the bottleneck is on something else other than the JSON column.
- We think, the `sales_order_item` table corresponds to [this model](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/bc1c7bac0b2d5b25491f34b17c055149780435fc/app/code/Magento/Sales/Model/Order/Item.php) in the `magento2` repository on GitHub, right? We also need pointers on how to navigate the Magento source code, if possible.

Please also refer to the DDL of the table in our data warehouse in the below details and let me know of any questions.

We highly appreciate any hints and suggestions.

**Details:**

```sql
/****** Object:  Table [msab_magento].[sales_order_item]    Script Date: 11/8/2023 5:08:01 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item](
    [item_id] [bigint] IDENTITY(3233417,1) NOT NULL,
    [order_id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [parent_item_id] [bigint] NULL,
    [quote_item_id] [bigint] NULL,
    [store_id] [int] NULL,
    [created_at] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [updated_at] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [product_id] [bigint] NULL,
    [product_type] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [product_options] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [weight] [decimal](12, 4) NULL,
    [is_virtual] [int] NULL,
    [sku] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [name] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [description] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [applied_rule_ids] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [additional_data] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [is_qty_decimal] [int] NULL,
    [no_discount] [int] NOT NULL,
    [qty_backordered] [decimal](12, 4) NULL,
    [qty_canceled] [decimal](12, 4) NULL,
    [qty_invoiced] [decimal](12, 4) NULL,
    [qty_ordered] [decimal](12, 4) NULL,
    [qty_refunded] [decimal](12, 4) NULL,
    [qty_shipped] [decimal](12, 4) NULL,
    [base_cost] [decimal](12, 4) NULL,
    [price] [decimal](12, 4) NOT NULL,
    [base_price] [decimal](12, 4) NOT NULL,
    [original_price] [decimal](12, 4) NULL,
    [base_original_price] [decimal](12, 4) NULL,
    [tax_percent] [decimal](12, 4) NULL,
    [tax_amount] [decimal](20, 4) NULL,
    [base_tax_amount] [decimal](20, 4) NULL,
    [tax_invoiced] [decimal](20, 4) NULL,
    [base_tax_invoiced] [decimal](20, 4) NULL,
    [discount_percent] [decimal](12, 4) NULL,
    [discount_amount] [decimal](20, 4) NULL,
    [base_discount_amount] [decimal](20, 4) NULL,
    [discount_invoiced] [decimal](20, 4) NULL,
    [base_discount_invoiced] [decimal](20, 4) NULL,
    [amount_refunded] [decimal](20, 4) NULL,
    [base_amount_refunded] [decimal](20, 4) NULL,
    [row_total] [decimal](20, 4) NOT NULL,
    [base_row_total] [decimal](20, 4) NOT NULL,
    [row_invoiced] [decimal](20, 4) NOT NULL,
    [base_row_invoiced] [decimal](20, 4) NOT NULL,
    [row_weight] [decimal](12, 4) NULL,
    [base_tax_before_discount] [decimal](20, 4) NULL,
    [tax_before_discount] [decimal](20, 4) NULL,
    [ext_order_item_id] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [locked_do_invoice] [int] NULL,
    [locked_do_ship] [int] NULL,
    [price_incl_tax] [decimal](20, 4) NULL,
    [base_price_incl_tax] [decimal](20, 4) NULL,
    [row_total_incl_tax] [decimal](20, 4) NULL,
    [base_row_total_incl_tax] [decimal](20, 4) NULL,
    [discount_tax_compensation_amount] [decimal](20, 4) NULL,
    [base_discount_tax_compensation_amount] [decimal](20, 4) NULL,
    [discount_tax_compensation_invoiced] [decimal](20, 4) NULL,
    [base_discount_tax_compensation_invoiced] [decimal](20, 4) NULL,
    [discount_tax_compensation_refunded] [decimal](20, 4) NULL,
    [base_discount_tax_compensation_refunded] [decimal](20, 4) NULL,
    [tax_canceled] [decimal](12, 4) NULL,
    [discount_tax_compensation_canceled] [decimal](20, 4) NULL,
    [tax_refunded] [decimal](20, 4) NULL,
    [base_tax_refunded] [decimal](20, 4) NULL,
    [discount_refunded] [decimal](20, 4) NULL,
    [base_discount_refunded] [decimal](20, 4) NULL,
    [free_shipping] [int] NOT NULL,
    [qty_returned] [decimal](12, 4) NOT NULL,
    [gift_message_id] [int] NULL,
    [gift_message_available] [int] NULL,
    [weee_tax_applied] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [weee_tax_applied_amount] [decimal](12, 4) NULL,
    [weee_tax_applied_row_amount] [decimal](12, 4) NULL,
    [weee_tax_disposition] [decimal](12, 4) NULL,
    [weee_tax_row_disposition] [decimal](12, 4) NULL,
    [base_weee_tax_applied_amount] [decimal](12, 4) NULL,
    [base_weee_tax_applied_row_amnt] [decimal](12, 4) NULL,
    [base_weee_tax_disposition] [decimal](12, 4) NULL,
    [base_weee_tax_row_disposition] [decimal](12, 4) NULL,
    [gw_id] [int] NULL,
    [gw_base_price] [decimal](12, 4) NULL,
    [gw_price] [decimal](12, 4) NULL,
    [gw_base_tax_amount] [decimal](12, 4) NULL,
    [gw_tax_amount] [decimal](12, 4) NULL,
    [gw_base_price_invoiced] [decimal](12, 4) NULL,
    [gw_price_invoiced] [decimal](12, 4) NULL,
    [gw_base_tax_amount_invoiced] [decimal](12, 4) NULL,
    [gw_tax_amount_invoiced] [decimal](12, 4) NULL,
    [gw_base_price_refunded] [decimal](12, 4) NULL,
    [gw_price_refunded] [decimal](12, 4) NULL,
    [gw_base_tax_amount_refunded] [decimal](12, 4) NULL,
    [gw_tax_amount_refunded] [decimal](12, 4) NULL,
    [event_id] [int] NULL,
    [giftregistry_item_id] [int] NULL,
    [business_area] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [custom_options_has_private_data] [smallint] NULL,
    [auto_ship] [smallint] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_sales_order_item_item_id] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [item_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 95, DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [order_id]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [parent_item_id]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [quote_item_id]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [store_id]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [created_at]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [updated_at]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [product_id]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [product_type]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT ((0.0000)) FOR [weight]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [is_virtual]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [sku]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [name]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [is_qty_decimal]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [no_discount]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT ((0.0000)) FOR [qty_backordered]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT ((0.0000)) FOR [qty_canceled]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT ((0.0000)) FOR [qty_invoiced]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT ((0.0000)) FOR [qty_ordered]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT ((0.0000)) FOR [qty_refunded]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT ((0.0000)) FOR [qty_shipped]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT ((0.0000)) FOR [base_cost]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT ((0.0000)) FOR [price]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT ((0.0000)) FOR [base_price]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [original_price]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [base_original_price]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT ((0.0000)) FOR [tax_percent]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT ((0.0000)) FOR [tax_amount]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT ((0.0000)) FOR [base_tax_amount]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT ((0.0000)) FOR [tax_invoiced]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT ((0.0000)) FOR [base_tax_invoiced]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT ((0.0000)) FOR [discount_percent]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT ((0.0000)) FOR [discount_amount]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT ((0.0000)) FOR [base_discount_amount]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT ((0.0000)) FOR [discount_invoiced]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT ((0.0000)) FOR [base_discount_invoiced]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT ((0.0000)) FOR [amount_refunded]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT ((0.0000)) FOR [base_amount_refunded]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT ((0.0000)) FOR [row_total]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT ((0.0000)) FOR [base_row_total]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT ((0.0000)) FOR [row_invoiced]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT ((0.0000)) FOR [base_row_invoiced]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT ((0.0000)) FOR [row_weight]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [base_tax_before_discount]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [tax_before_discount]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [ext_order_item_id]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [locked_do_invoice]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [locked_do_ship]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [price_incl_tax]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [base_price_incl_tax]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [row_total_incl_tax]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [base_row_total_incl_tax]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [discount_tax_compensation_amount]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [base_discount_tax_compensation_amount]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [discount_tax_compensation_invoiced]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [base_discount_tax_compensation_invoiced]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [discount_tax_compensation_refunded]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [base_discount_tax_compensation_refunded]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [tax_canceled]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [discount_tax_compensation_canceled]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [tax_refunded]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [base_tax_refunded]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [discount_refunded]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [base_discount_refunded]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [free_shipping]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT ((0.0000)) FOR [qty_returned]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [gift_message_id]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [gift_message_available]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [weee_tax_applied_amount]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [weee_tax_applied_row_amount]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [weee_tax_disposition]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [weee_tax_row_disposition]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [base_weee_tax_applied_amount]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [base_weee_tax_applied_row_amnt]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [base_weee_tax_disposition]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [base_weee_tax_row_disposition]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [gw_id]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [gw_base_price]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [gw_price]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [gw_base_tax_amount]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [gw_tax_amount]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [gw_base_price_invoiced]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [gw_price_invoiced]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [gw_base_tax_amount_invoiced]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [gw_tax_amount_invoiced]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [gw_base_price_refunded]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [gw_price_refunded]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [gw_base_tax_amount_refunded]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [gw_tax_amount_refunded]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [event_id]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [giftregistry_item_id]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [custom_options_has_private_data]
GO

ALTER TABLE [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [auto_ship]
GO

EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'MS_SSMA_SOURCE', @value=N'msab_magento.sales_order_item' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'msab_magento', @level1type=N'TABLE',@level1name=N'sales_order_item'
GO
```

Comment: What types of compression have you tried?

Comment: We used page-level compression on the table and its indexes, e.g., for compressing the table, we used the command `alter table [msab_magento].[sales_order_item] rebuild partition = all with (data_compression = page);`.

Comment: SQL Server cannot compress LOB data **at all**, so you are wasting your time looking at page/row compression. Storing it as UTF8 collation in a `varchar` column could save up to 50% space in many cases with little effort. Even so seems hardly worth it for such a small DB, just get a bigger drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bear in mind your varchar(max) are stored off-table and will not be compressed with the "flick the switch" compression modes.

Consider

a) Unpicking the JSON and storing it as relational data if possible

b) changing your column to varbinary(max) and adding a compression step at your code level, as a trigger or SP.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/compress-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

To be honest, a 20GB database does not sound worth compressing.

Comment: varchar(max) is stored on-row by default, and only stored off-row if too large to fit on an 8k page.  sp_tableoption can by used to force 'large value types out of row'.  But you are correct that they are never compressed.